# WhereNotIn inside WhereHas

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

why whereNotIn doesn't work inside whereHas?

```
Model::whereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
                    $query->whereNotIn('title',['X,'Y','Z']);
                })
```

I posted as answer workarounds but can someone explain it or it's BUG?
Laravel 6

Answer (score 1):

Some workarounds:

```
            ->whereDoesntHave('statuses', function ($query) {
                $query->whereIn('title',['X','Y','Z']);
            })
```

or

```
            ->whereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
                $query->whereIn('title', ['X,'Y','Z']);
                $query->having(\DB::raw("COUNT(table_statuses.id)"), '=', 0);
            })
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not a bug, it only works if the relationship is one to one if it one to many you have to use whereDoesnHave

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31317365)