# Exclude wheredoesnthave or operator

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

When I run this query I get 2 rows

```
            $data->whereHas('statuses', function($q){
                $q->where('statuses.title', 'P');
            });
            $data->whereHas('statuses', function($q){
                $q->where('statuses.title', 'U');
            });
```

But with this It's not excluding 2 rows but a lot more:

```
            $data->whereDoesntHave('statuses', function($q){
                $q->where('statuses.title', 'P');
            });
            $data->whereDoesntHave('statuses', function($q){
                $q->where('statuses.title', 'U');
            });
```

I need to exclude 2 rows fetched from code above.
I found experimentally solution but I don't understand this logic:

```
             $data->whereDoesntHave('statuses', function($q){
                $q->where('statuses.title', 'P');
            });
            $data->orWhereDoesntHave('statuses', function($q){
                $q->where('statuses.title', 'U');
            });
```

Why 'or' behave like 'and' in whereDoesntHave? It's oppsite.
Why It works ;)?

What I want is: "Give me rows which doesn't have statuses P AND U simultaneous" and I'm getting it but the 'or' there is weird.

Similar to my other question: [WhereNotIn inside WhereHas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889641/wherenotin-inside-wherehas/66889642#66889642)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In boolean logic, negating  `a AND b` results in `NOT a OR NOT b`. This is from [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

In your case you have

```
$a = $data->whereHas('statuses', function($q){
    $q->where('statuses.title', 'P');
});
$b = $data->whereHas('statuses', function($q){
     $q->where('statuses.title', 'U');
});
```

so negating that you get the result that works. `whereDoesntHave` is essentially `NOT whereHas` and the `orWhereDoesntHave` is to indicate the `OR` between the two parts so

```
$data->whereDoesntHave('statuses', function($q){
    $q->where('statuses.title', 'P');
});
$data->orWhereDoesntHave('statuses', function($q){
    $q->where('statuses.title', 'U');
});
```

is essentially `NOT a OR NOT b`

Answer (score 0):

It should works for you.

```
$data->orWhereDoesntHave('statuses', function($q){
    $q->where('statuses.title', 'P')->where('statuses.title', 'U');
});
```